# Spa application with many Windows open

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

Is it possible to have many Windows opened in SPA application with mvc 4.

I mean i have a list of user. Open a user get me to a view and then i can go back to the same view and open another. And then choose to direct go to the first opened user that hold the state of that user.

I don't know if you understand My question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be misunderstanding what a single page application is. It plays by the exact same rules as a regular webpage except you do not navigate away from the page.

There are no such thing as windows etc, they are simply divs emulating real application windows. What you describe is perfectly possible you just need to create the correct divs and position/populate them correctly. For example, sometime ago I wrote a window manager in KO that mimics the windows 7 look and feel.

You can find it here.

https://github.com/madcapnmckay/Knockout-UI

I would caution that single page apps are an advanced topic and you should be very wary of delving into them before understand the implications.

**EDIT**

There are many ways to separate your viewModels. I always have one master viewModel for the whole app. In your case I would create a UserViewModel class in javascript and new up a new one before adding it to some observable array.

```
var user1 = new UserViewModel(ajaxdata);
self.users.push(user1);
var user2 = new UserViewModel(ajaxdata);
self.users.push(user2);

<div data-bind="foreach: users">
     <div>
        ... your user window markup goes here
     </div>
</div>
```

You could optionally use the template binding instead of an inline template. As for loading the data that is upto you. You could perform an ajax call to fetch the user data before newing up the UserViewModel, or you might load all the data at the start and new them up when you want them to display.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But i dont get how i should seperate the viewmodels when i have 2 user divs on the page "open". How do i do this. I know everything is just divs.

Comment: How about the new user that i open. Should the new div be downloaded and how about say ko template. Do they find the fight one in this enviroment.

Comment: One more questions. How about jquery selector. Should you always use your surrounding div in that.

Comment: Whoo thanks. That helped a lot.
I did a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Uv5Ds/49/ How can I make the user template div be a own page with its own viewmodel so that I can test it without the parent div. is it possible

Comment: If you just want to test that vm in isolation as well as in the foreach simply move the template div into a named template eg <script id="mytemplate"></div> and use the template binding in place of the foreach.

Comment: @user1199595 - If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer. Regards.